# ant machine name property

Tags: windows, linux, ant

Is there a way to get the machine name as ant property, for both Linux and Windows OS.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

On Windows the hostname is in the environment variable "COMPUTERNAME", on Linux the environment variable is "HOSTNAME". Because ant properties are immutable something like the following should work:

```
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="env.HOSTNAME" value="${env.COMPUTERNAME}"/>
<echo message="hostname = ${env.HOSTNAME}"/>
```

i.e. import the environment as properties prefixed with env. Then set env.HOSTNAME to be the value of env.COMPUTERNAME unless env.HOSTNAME is already set in which case the 2nd line will have no effect. After that use env.HOSTNAME where the hostname is required.

Answer (score 34):

```
<exec executable="hostname" outputproperty="computer.hostname"/>
```

will work on linux and windows

Comment: I think this is more reliable. Back when we were using COMPUTERNAME, on SOME machines the casing of the value did not match the casing of the name of the machine. 'hostname' has so far always matched.

Comment: +1.  I tried the accepted answer and it failed.  This one worked great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to find the local machine's hostname is by using Ant's [`HostInfo`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/hostinfo.html) task. This will work across all platforms and is natively supported by Ant.

```
<hostinfo prefix="host." />
<echo message="My hostname is '${host.NAME}'" />
```

Comment: It looks like this should be the "right" answer, but when I use this (at least, on my Debian Sid system), `${host.NAME}` is set to `localhost`. Running `hostname` as per Rebse's answer returns the actual host name I want.

Answer (score 3):

Copy the value for Unix into the Windows version.  Then you can use ${env.COMPUTERNAME}.

```
<property name="env.COMPUTERNAME" value="${env.HOSTNAME}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the environment variables $HOSTNAME (UNIX) and %COMPUTERNAME% (Windows) for this. You can check to see if the environment variable HOSTNAME has been defined and, if not, you can then use the environment variable COMPUTERNAME, assuming it is defined. As a fallback, you can use "unknown".

Answer (score -1):

I would write a custom Ant task.

Once you start writing you own tasks you will find that Ant gets a lot more fun and easy to use. You don't need strange solutions that are hard to understand.

Once the task is written you would just do something like:

```
<my:hostname property"hostname" />
```