# How to get fully qualified hostname using Ant

Tags: ant

I am using Ant as our setup script for our server, and we need to get the fully qualified name of our server. How can I get it using Ant, or is is possible in Ant?

The fully qualified hostname is like: xxx.company.com

Comment: See also [ant machine name property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196989/ant-machine-name-property)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<exec executable="hostname" outputproperty="computer.hostname"/>
```

will work on linux and windows, otherwise use the groovy solution from Marc O'Connor
Also nslookup will work on linux and windows, if you need the fullhostname you have to parse for the entry after Name: in `nslookup ServerName` output, use :

```
<groovy>
properties.'hostname' = "hostname".execute().text
//or
properties.'hostname' = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()

properties.'hostnamefull' = "nslookup ${"hostname".execute().text}".execute().text.find(/Name:\s(.+)/).split(/:\s+/)[1]
</groovy>

<echo>
$${hostname} => ${hostname}
$${hostnamefull} => ${hostnamefull}
</echo>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is an Ant task called [`HostInfo`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/hostinfo.html) that you can use to set properties containing the host name and domain of the current machine.

Alternatively, if you're running on Linux/Unix you could just call out to the `hostname` command:

```
<exec executable="hostname" outputproperty="myhostname">
  <arg line="-f"/>
</exec>
```

The fully-qualified host name is then available in `${myhostname}`.

**EDIT:** For a fully platform-independent solution, a custom task something like this (untested) should do the job:

```
public class GetHost extends Task
{
    private String property;

    public void setProperty(String property)
    {
        this.property = property;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute() throws BuildException
    {
        if (property == null || property.length() == 0)
        {
            throw new BuildException("Property name must be specified.");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                String hostName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
                getProject().setProperty(property, hostName);
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                throw new BuildException(ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
<GetHost property="myhostname" />
```

Comment: I wanted something that could work on all platforms. Also hostinfo is for set not for get, is it?

Comment: @performanceuser `HostInfo` sets properties with values it obtains.  However, having just tried it it seems less useful than I thought.  If you don't specify the host it defaults to the local host but instead of getting the actual host name it seems to set `HOST` to `localhost` and `DOMAIN` to `localdomain`. A third option that I didn't include is to create your own custom task that calls `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`. That's a bit more work but will be cross-platform (maybe someone else has already created such a task).

Comment: i found that using `<hostinfo prefix="host" />` is not the same as `<hostinfo prefix="host" host="localhost" />` with the later one i got useful informations, the first had always `host.NAME=localhost`

Answer (score 2):

Rehashing an answer I did for [Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7441265/look-up-hostname-from-maven/7450469#7450469) :-)

Use an embedded groovy script to perform the Java hostname lookup:

```
       <groovy>
            properties["hostname"] = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
        </groovy>
```

## Example

Project is self-documenting:

```
$ ant -p
Buildfile: /home/mark/tmp/build.xml

    This is a demo project answering the followng stackoverflow question:

        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653733

    First install 3rd party dependencies

        ant bootstrap 

    Then run the build

        ant

    Expect the following output

        print-hostname:
            [echo] Hostname: ?????
```

### build.xml

```
<project name="demo" default="print-hostname">

    <description>
    This is a demo project answering the followng stackoverflow question:

        https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653733

    First install 3rd party dependencies

        ant bootstrap 

    Then run the build

        ant

    Expect the following output

        print-hostname:
            [echo] Hostname: ?????

    </description>

    <target name="bootstrap" description="Install 3rd party dependencies">
        <mkdir dir="${user.home}/.ant/lib"/>
        <get dest="${user.home}/.ant/lib/groovy-all.jar" src="http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/2.1.0/groovy-all-2.1.0.jar"/>
    </target>

    <target name="print-hostname" description="Retrieve and print the hostname">
        <taskdef name="groovy" classname="org.codehaus.groovy.ant.Groovy"/>

        <groovy>
            properties["hostname"] = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()
        </groovy>

        <echo message="Hostname: ${hostname}"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to write a javascript **scriptdef** that sets this information in properties.

```
<scriptdef name="get-hostame" language="javascript">
    <attribute name="prefix" /> <![CDATA[
        importClass(java.net.InetAddress);
        address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        prefix = attributes.get("prefix");
        project.setNewProperty(prefix + ".hostname", address.getHostName());
        project.setNewProperty(prefix + ".fqdn", address.getCanonicalHostName());
        project.setNewProperty(prefix + ".address", address.getHostAddress());
    ]]>
</scriptdef>
```

You can call it like this:

```
<get-hostame prefix="uwi.host" />
```

Here is the result:

```
[echoproperties] uwi.host.address=10.666.666.666
[echoproperties] uwi.host.fqdn=myhost.stackoverflow.com
[echoproperties] uwi.host.hostname=myhos
```

This is based on some advice I found here:
http://grokbase.com/t/ant/user/051sygfj9b/any-way-to-get-at-the-machine-name

Answer (score 0):

use enviroment

```
<property name="hostname" value="${env.COMPUTERNAME}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript which is built-in

```
<script language="javascript">//<![CDATA[
    project.setProperty("hostname", Packages.java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName());
    project.setProperty("hostname-full", Packages.java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getCanonicalHostName());
//]]></script>
<echo message="hostname=${hostname}"/>
<echo message="hostname-full=${hostname-full}"/>
```