# obtain IP address and store it in a property - ant

Tags: ant, properties, ip

I am quite new to Ant and I found this piece of code to obtain the local ip address:

```
<target name="if_windows" depends="checkos" if="isWindows">
    <exec executable="cmd" outputproperty="myHostName">
        <arg value="/c" />
        <arg value="hostname"/>
    </exec>

    <exec executable="cmd" outputproperty="infraServerIPTemp" >
        <arg value="/c"/>
        <arg value="FOR /f &quot;tokens=1 delims=:&quot; %d IN ('ping ${myHostName} -4 -n 1 ^| find /i &quot;reply&quot;') DO FOR /F &quot;tokens=3 delims= &quot; %g IN (&quot;%d&quot;) DO echo infraServerIP=%g > myIP.properties"/>
    </exec>

    <property file="myIP.properties"/>
</target>
```

Now the thing is I've tried for hours to get it inside a property instead of a propertyfile. But I just can't manage to get it done. Does anyone can help me a hand here?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you looked at https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/hostinfo.html

Comment: Yeah but cant acquire an ip and put it in a property. As I said, haven't got a lot of ant experience.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<target name="Foo2">
    <property environment="env"/>
    <property name="env.HOSTNAME" value="${env.COMPUTERNAME}"/><!--On Windows the hostname is in the environment variable 'COMPUTERNAME', on Linux the environment variable is 'HOSTNAME'-->
    <hostinfo prefix="host" host="${env.HOSTNAME}" />
    <echo>${host.ADDR4}</echo>
</target>
```

I'm not sure if there is a easy way to do it - IP may depends on your Internet adapters. In my case I got 2 virtual addapters and this soulution didn't work.

Check [How to get fully qualified hostname using Ant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14653733/how-to-get-fully-qualified-hostname-using-ant) topic